# MvvmCross Listview how show an action menu

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, mvvmcross, floating-action-menu

I make use of Xamarin and MvvmCross to develop an Android app. I would like to show an action menu at the bottom of a listview when the user makes a long press on a listview item, like the attached screenshoot.

I can use "ItemLongClick" to detect the long click, but I don't know how to make the action menu visible.

```
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AllItems; ItemLongClick ShowMenuCommand;"
```

Can you give some tips how to implement this with use of Xamarin and MvvmCross?

Many thanks,

Tuan

[image: Listview context menu]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library 
https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar but it's not integrated with MvvmCross